# Adding a leaderboard into HTML using MySQL values to rank

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a MySQL table with the following columns:

```
UserID, username, firstname, lastname, password, wealth
```

I've written PHP to write values and retrieve values from the wealth column, but I am completely lost on how to create a leaderboard.

Essentially, I'd like to rank the top 5 users based upon their 'wealth'.

Would anyone mind helping me with this?

Really stuck at the moment.

Thanks all.

Comment: Make query with `ORDER BY wealth DESC` and `LIMIT 5` to get top five rows.

Comment: Explain exactly where you have been lost ?

Comment: If you have wealth values in integer.. you can do it by ordering

Comment: I don't understand which part of this problem you're stuck on.

Comment: There's no need to downvote the question. I'm sorry if I didn't explain it correctly, but I am stuck on creating a leaderboard. I don't know where to start. I already have a 'wealth' column with values assigned to usernames, but I have no clue how to rank them.

Comment: @PatrykUszyński Thank you. Then can I echo the output? Or will the output automatically appear if I was to use (data) in a separate document?

Comment: @Caspar next, you will need to fetch the data from query, iterate throught elements and print them one by one

Comment: @PatrykUszyński Not familiar with how to iterate throughout elements and printing them one by one... mind explaining? Thanks.

Comment: Down votes are for questions which show no research effort, are unclear, or unuseful. I think there's a very good case for down voting (and closing) this question.

Comment: @Caspar It depends on what you are using for queries. To iterate means run in loop, for ex. [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Comment: Got it. Thank you @PatrykUszyński

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how to do it with PDO. PDO is objective representation of your database connection and it supports parameter bindings.

```
// Setup database connection
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb', 'username', 'password');

// Make a query
$stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY wealth DESC LIMIT 5");

// Display data while fetching
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo $row['username'].' has '.$row['wealth'] . '<br />';
}
```